# PHP Form Data with Multi-dimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, multidimensional-array

Say I have a form containing an input field with

`name="my_options[my_elements][1][name]"`

and another with

`name="my_options[my_elements][1][category]"`

When I submit the form all is well and a new array containing name and category keys/values is added to the `my_elements` array in the `my_options` array in the DB.

I can also use `name="my_options[my_elements][][name]"`

to create a new array within `my_options[my_elements]`

However I obviously can't then use `name="my_options[my_elements][][category]"`

as this will put the category value into a further new array.

Is there a way of dynamically keeping track of the position of the new array created with the first `[]` so that values can be added at that particular level of the multidimensional array?

To clarify, I'm looking to dynamically add elements to the following array:

```
'my_options' =>
 array (size ?)
  0 => 
   'my_elements' => 
     array (size=2)
      0 => 
         array (size=2)
            'name' =>  'name 1'
            'category' =>  'cat 1'
      1 => 
         array (size=2)
            'name' =>  'name 2'
            'category' =>  'cat 2'
```

`

Comment: I doubt there is a way to do this without manually specifying the index as you already did/tried. Is it that big an issue? You probably already have an index value somewhere on HTML side, whether it is the key of a foreach loop or a number you increment for a dynamic form.

Comment: The problem is that the form can have rows deleted on the front end via JQuery, which leads to non-existent index issues on the back end. I probably will need to re-index the rows somehow and interpolate the row number into the array expression before posting.

Comment: How does it lead to non-existent indexes? If you delete a row, then it actually seems logical to no longer send its index to the backend, to let it know it got deleted. If you send rows 1, 3 and 4 you know it's the same rows 1, 3 and 4 from before but row 2 is now absent so it got removed.

Comment: It could just be the fact that I'm displaying the existing rows using a for loop going from 0 to the length of the array -1 for the keys. May using a foreach loop would solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use array definitions in the html part of your application.

Stick with a input name, like `name="category"` and in your php file fetch the submitted data and organize it in an array the way you want it.

assuming you use POST as form method:
`$category = $_POST['category'];`

(don't forget to validate the input)

Comment: The context is the WordPress setttngs API, and the way I've shown is the standard approach I believe, although the options usually have fewer dimensions. I thought this was a generic PHP issue, though.